# Divergence on domain's boundary

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

As an example, the divergence of a 2D vector field $\mathbf{u}=(u,v)$ is defined as $u_x + v_y$. Consider $\mathbf{u}=(1,0)$, the divergence is zero. Now we modify this field by making those on the $-x$ half plane zero, meaning $\mathbf{u}=(0,0)$, then we have a piecewise vector field. It is easy to show that the divergence of this field is $\delta(x)$. For this purpose you can either directly apply $u_x+v_y$, or use the original definition by taking the limit of a surface integral divided by area.

My question is how to generalize this. For example, if instead of making vectors on the $-x$ half plane zero, what if we make those outside of the unit circle zero? Then we have
$$
\mathbf{u} = (1,0) \quad \text{when} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1\,\quad\text{and}\quad(0,0)\,\text{otherwise}
$$
What's the divergence on the unit circle? I guess the local normal direction should matter?

Lastly, what if there is "nothing" outside of the unit circle? Can divergence still be defined in this case?

Comment: I am not sure if I get this, but are you asking what $div : S^1\subset {\mathbb{R}}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ would be? ($S^1$ is the unit sphere).

Comment: @hal4math If you are referring to the example, yes. A discontinuous vector field that equals (1,0)/(0,0) inside-on/outside a unit circle, what's its divergence.

Comment: Do you know what a distributional derivative is? I think that would be the general approach you are asking for.